# Is the order reported by 'sys.path' the order in which packages are searched?

Tags: python, path, package

Does the order in which entries occur in the Python `sys.path` correspond to the order in which packages are found? For example I have

```
>>> from pprint import pprint     
>>> pprint(sys.path)
['',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.14.dev-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.8.0.dev_3abd869_20121222-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymc-2.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.13_git-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.12.0.dev_d631749_20121222-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/statsmodels-0.5.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/readline-6.2.4.1-py2.7-macosx-10.7-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six-1.2.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyzmq-2.2.0.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/patsy-0.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xattr-0.6.4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/astropy-0.3.dev2837-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

so that, in general, I've got

```
['',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/PKG_WITH_EGG.egg',
 ...
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 ...
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

Does that mean that if a package I install (in 'site-packages') happens to have a `.egg`, it will supersede a version of the same package that might be in 'Extras' but that those (in 'site-packages') that do not have an `.egg` will be superseded by any version in 'Extras'?

Comment: Yes, modules are generally searched for in that order, but submodules are searched in the base modules tree.

Comment: @Keith: So if I have a module that's in 'Extras' and in 'site-packages', the 'site-packages' version would only be used if it happened to be in the form of an EGG? (If so, I guess that means you're [not meant to have the same package in 'Extras` and 'site-packages'](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14881205/656912).)

Comment: Not an egg, a package or module. Eggs are containers (subdirectories or zip files) that if in the sys.path are searched for modules. site-packages is a directory that is searched for modules or packages. A package is a directory with an `__init__.py` file in it.

Comment: @Keith: Not sure I get that. If I have, say `somepkg-YY` in 'Extras' and (1) `somepkg` (and perhaps `somepkg-XX.egg-info`) in 'site-packages' does version 'YY' get loaded; (2) if I instead have `somepkg-XX.egg` in 'site-packages' (which then seems to get added to the 'sys.path') does version 'XX' get loaded?

Comment: egg-info is not searched by the Python interpreter, and .egg directories are not searched by python unless it is in the sys.path. You can use my [pywhich](https://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/core/bin/pywhich) tool to tell you which one it found.

Comment: @Keith: Yes, assume the an .egg in 'site-packages' gets added to sys.path (which is the pattern I see). What happens in (1) vs (2)?

Comment: If you mean in `.../Extras/lib/python` then if it finds `somepkg` there it will use that, since it is before `.../site-packages`.

Comment: @Keith: Yes. So if the package is configured as in (1) it will use the version in 'Extras' and if as in (2) (and the .egg is put on the path like the others) it will use the version under 'site-packages'.